# Return from child qml to main one

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have several `QML` files, main one is the one that opens the `ApplicationWindow` when ever I try to get back from child `QML` to main, new window is opened again!
how can I prevent of doing this?
I thought that enabling a flag in child `QML`, but there may be other ways!
I tried `stackview` in `QML`

### Is there any way to prevent from opening new page when I get back to main `QML`?

Comment: Can you add more details to your question? Share some of your problematic code. How are you trying to "get back from child QML to main"? Are you just using `StackView push` everywhere ?

Comment: No I use `StackView.replace`, only thing I want is to remove extra page, opens after I call the `main.qml`

Comment: For example I want to go to `A.qml` from `main.qml` then by pressing a key in `A.qml` I want to get back to `main.qml` without having `main.qml` destroyed, plz help me then

Comment: You should use push on the stackview to add the child qml, and then when the key is pressed you pop() to remove the top-most item from the stack (which should be your child qml)

Comment: i dont understand why people down vote this question its a clear question , if you dont know the answer just leave the question alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a loader in main window and call every page into that loader when ever you need to change page just change loader's source

```
Window {
    Loader{
        id:myLoader
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "LoginPage.qml"
    }
    Connections{
        target: myLoader.item
        onBack_clicked:{
            loginid = ""
            myLoader.source = "LoginPage.qml"
        }
        onSetting_clicked:{
            myLoader.source = "Setting.qml"
        }
    }
}
```

and for child qml files : (for me Setting.qml)

```
Item {
signal back_clicked()
Button {
                    id: button1
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.rightMargin: 15
                    onClicked: {
                        back_clicked()
                    }
       }
}
```

but if you want to not destroy old page use SwipeView Or StackView:

```
SwipeView {
    id: swipeView
    clip: true
    currentIndex: 0
    Item{
       id:firstPage
       clip:true
       //your page
    }
    Item{
       id:secondPage
       clip:true
       //your page
    }
}
```

and to change pages just change currentIndex

```
swipeView.currentIndex = 1
```

**UPDATE:**

```
StackView {
    id: stackView

    initialItem: one
}
Component {
    id: one
    Item{//your first page }
}

Component {
    id: two
    Item{//your second page }
}
```

and to push your pages :

```
stackView.push({ item: two})
//or
stackView.push("MySecondView.qml")
```

to get back to old or main page just pop it :

```
stackView.pop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I get the answer
The only problem I face is that at the next returns (not first returns) data not sending correctly! I guess I should kill the pages first then return!

Comment: @EhsanAsleMostafa which way you used? loader or swipeView?

Comment: @EhsanAsleMostafa try StackView , i Updated my answer , i'm using SwipeView and changing pages does not affect values in page for example TextField Value will stay same after changing SwipeView currentIndex

Comment: make sure you have one file with root element of `Window` or `ApplicationWindow` others should be `Page` or `Item` or `Rectangle` or whatever you want to show but not windows you can use `Popup`s too, to have modal pages

Comment: I use `StackView` and in the other `QML` files I use `Page` I have to change pages as the signal arrives, and I think duplication affects my programm? How can I destroy a `QML`?

Comment: @EhsanAsleMostafa i dont think thats possible,if you share some code , maybe i could help with that

Comment: @EhsanAsleMostafa i checked that use `SwipeView ` your problem solved

Comment: Thanks for your help , I tried `SwipeView` and It works well, and now signal emitted well and not received!, I think I should start another question!